# Why $\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m} = \binom{n}{m}2^{n-m},0< m< n$?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, binomial-theorem

I tried to use induction and I got 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=m}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{n}k\\ m\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ m\end{array}\right) 2^{n-1-m}$
So 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=m}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{n}k\\ m\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ n+1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ m\end{array}\right)$
And 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=m}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)2^{n-m} + \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ n+1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ m\end{array}\right)$
I don't know what to do now. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try completing your attempt using induction, try double induction on $m$ and $n$. Both sides of the identity equal $1$ when $n=m$.  Now suppose the identity holds for a particular $m$ and for all $n\ge m$.  Furthermore, suppose it holds for $m+1$ and a particular $n$.  We now show that it also holds for $m+1$ and $n+1$.

Evaluate
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\binom{k}{m+1}&=\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)\binom{k}{m+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m+1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}\left(\binom{k-1}{m+1}+\binom{k-1}{m}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m+1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m+1}+\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}\\
&=2\binom{n}{m+1}2^{n-m-1}+\binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{m+1}2^{n-m}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{m+1}2^{(n+1)-(m+1)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
In the first, second, and fifth steps the Pascal's triangle recurrence has been used.  The induction hypothesis has been used in the fourth step.  Induction on $n$ shows the identity holds for $m+1$ and all $n\ge m+1$.  Consequently, by induction on $m$, it holds for all $0\le m\le n$.

Comment: Very good! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following scenario:

> You have $n$ numbered, white balls. You want to color $m$ of them blue, and some number of the remaining balls (anywhere form $0$ to $n-m$) red.

You could do this by first picking out $k$ balls that will get a color at all, and then from among those choose $m$ to make blue, and make the rest red. You could, alternately, do this by first picking the $m$ balls to color blue, then for each of the remaining $n-m$ balls decide whether you want to color it red or not.

If you want to know in *how many ways* this coloring can be done, these two approaches give two different-looking expressions for how many ways this can be done. But ultimately, those two expressions must yield the same final value, as they count the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use $${n \choose k}{k \choose m}={n \choose m}{n-m \choose k-m}$$
Then $$S=\sum_{k=m}^{n}{n \choose k}{k \choose m}= {n \choose m} \sum_{k=m}^{n} {n-m \choose k-m}= {n \choose m} \sum_{p=0}^{n-m} {n-m \choose p}={n \choose m} 2^{n-m}$$